# echarts-for-react programmatically expand and collapse leaves in tree

Tags: reactjs

I am using echarts-for-react tree chart. It is same as link given below:
https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=tree-basic

(Note: Add "initialTreeDepth: 1" in above link editor so that tree is opened at depth 1 initially)
Is there a way to programmatically collapse rest of leave/node at depth 1 when particular leave in same depth is expanded? Like in above link if I click on "analytics" leave/node then rest of the leaves/nodes(i.e animate, data, display, etc) is collapsed.

I am using react & echars-for-react version "echarts-for-react": "^3.0.1"